# Select One of OneToMany where One does not have a certain Many result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a `WorkOrder` that has many `LineItem`s. I'd like to select only `WorkOrder`s that have a certain `LineItem`, but do not have another `LineItem`. The concrete example is selecting all `WorkOrder`s that have a `LineItem` for buying new tires, but not for buying new *trailer* tires.

**Table Data:**

```
WorkOrder
id  create_date
1   2015-01-01 12:00:00
2   2015-01-01 12:00:00

LineItems
id  order_id    line_type
1   1           tire disposal
2   1           new trailer tires
3   1           tire pro-tection plan
4   2           tire disposal
5   2           new car tires
6   2           tire pro-tection plan
```

**Desired Results:**

```
WorkOrder
id  create_date
2   2015-01-01 12:00:00
```

**Current Code:**

```
$search = [
    'disposal',
    'rotation',
    'pro-tection',
];
$selects = [
    'Customer.*',
    'Vehicle.*',
    'WorkOrder.*',
    'max(WorkOrder.create_date) as create_date',
];

$orders = $this->prospectInstance->getDatabase()->table('WorkOrder')
    ->join('LineItems', 'LineItems.order_id', '=', 'WorkOrder.id')
    ->join('Customer', 'Customer.customer_id', '=', 'WorkOrder.customer_id')
    ->join('Vehicle', 'Vehicle.customer_id', '=', 'Customer.customer_id')
    ->selectRaw(implode(',', $selects))
    ->whereNotNull('Customer.email')
    // this does nothing
    ->where('LineItems.line_type', 'not like', '%trailer%')
    ->where(function($query) use ($search)
    {
        foreach ($search as $term)
        {
            $query->orWhere('LineItems.line_type', 'like', "%$term%");
        }
    })
    ->groupBy('WorkOrder.customer_id')
    ->get();
```

The generated SQL query for `$orders` is:

```
select
    Customer.*,
    Vehicle.*,
    WorkOrder.*,
    max(WorkOrder.create_date) as create_date 
from
    `WorkOrder` 
inner join
    `LineItems` 
        on `LineItems`.`order_id` = `WorkOrder`.`id` 
inner join
    `Customer` 
        on `Customer`.`customer_id` = `WorkOrder`.`customer_id` 
inner join
    `Vehicle` 
        on `Vehicle`.`customer_id` = `Customer`.`customer_id` 
where
    `Customer`.`email` is not null 
    and `LineItems`.`line_type` not like ? 
    and (
        `LineItems`.`line_type` like ? 
        or `LineItems`.`line_type` like ? 
        or `LineItems`.`line_type` like ?
    ) 
group by
    `WorkOrder`.`customer_id`
```

As it stands, the current condition checking whether or not a `LineItem` is for a new set of trailer tires doesn't do anything. It simply ignores the row and still gives the resulting `WorkOrder` since it matches all the other terms.

How would I select `WorkOrder`s that contain `LineItem`s for the specified terms **only** if there are no `LineItem`s that contain the term `trailer`?

**Notes:**

- The reason I don't directly select where the line type is `new car tires` is because they're all over the place. The only reliable way to select work orders with new tires is to check whether they have line items for a tire disposal fee or a tire warranty.

Comment: not sure about laravel, but in normal sql you would add a subquery to the where clause and say `and WorkOrder.id not in (select LineItems.order_id where LineItems.line_type like '%trailer%'`. Essentially getting a list of things you don't want and saying `where workorder.id not in (list of things I don't want)`

Comment: Makes perfect sense - thanks!